# Передача переменной в новое окно

Tags: javascript

У меня есть html форма нового окна и я хотел бы вставить туда переменную из основного html файла c js, но не могу понять как это сделать. Нужно что бы имя которое пользователь ввел в поле ввода появлялось в виде текста в новом окне. Вот мой код, помогите пожалуйста.

Скрипт основной функции:

```
<script>
function hello_Programm() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var new_window = window.open("form.html", "hello", "width=500,height=500");
  return name;
}
</script>
```

HTML основной страницы:

```
 <body>
    <center><p class="h1">Welcome!</p></center>
    <hr>
    <input class="text_form" type="text" placeholder="Mary Jane" id="name">
    <input type="button" value="Hello!" onClick="hello_Programm()">
  </body>
```

HTML и JS нового окна

```
<body>
  <center><p><script>//здесь должна быть переменная с именем пользователя</script></p></center>
  <hr>
  <p>Take this bouquet as a gift:</p>
  <img src="rose.png">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
<script>
function hello_Programm() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var new_window = window.open("form.html", "hello", "width=500,height=500");
  new_window.onload = function() {
    new_window.document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = name;
  }
  return name;
}
</script>
```

HTML и JS нового окна:

```
<body>
  <div id="test"> </div> //в этот див вставится Ваше содержимое
  <hr>
  <p>Take this bouquet as a gift:</p>
  <img src="rose.png">
</body>
```

Comment: Увы не вышло но, я  еще поищу какие нибудь способы)

Comment: У меня все передается, в хроме и файрфоксе все отображается. Что собственно не работает? В консоли есть ошибки?

Comment: Не выдает никаких ошибок, но строка даже не выводится